# ListView CheckedItems find item by name

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I need to check if an item with a particular name exists in the CheckedItems collection of a ListView.

So far I've tried:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(itemName);

if (listView1.CheckedItems.IndexOf(item) >= 0)
   return true;
```

and

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(itemName);

if (listView1.CheckedItems.Contains(item))
   return true;
```

Neither of those worked. Is there a way to do this without looping through CheckedItems and checking them one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can benefit `LINQ` for this purpose:

```
bool itemChecked =  listView1.CheckedItems.OfType<ListViewItem>()
                             .Any(i => i.Text == itemText);
//You can also retrieve the item with itemText using FirstOrDefault()
var checkedItem = listView1.CheckedItems.OfType<ListViewItem>()
                                        .FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Text == itemText);
if(checkedItem != null) { //do you work...}
```

You can also use the `ContainsKey` to determine if the item (with name being `itemName`) is checked:

```
bool itemChecked = listView1.CheckedItems.ContainsKey(itemName);
```

Comment: LINQ method above worked when I changed `i.Name` to `i.Text`. If you update your answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Dr.Greenthumb that's because you said `with a particular name exists` in your question, of course if you meant `Text`, changing it to `Text` would work. If so the `ContainsKey` can't be used because it's used for `Name` not `Text`.

Comment: I initially thought I could find it by name, but when I added listView1.CheckedItems to the watch, there was no `name` parameter. Also you are right, `ContainsKey` didn't work when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of newing up a `ListViewItem` and do this instead:

```
ListViewItem itemYouAreLookingFor = listView1.FindItemWithText("NameToLookFor");

// Did we find a match?
if (itemYouAreLookingFor != null)
{
    // Yes, so find out if the item is checked or not?
    if(itemYouAreLookingFor.Checked)
    {
        // Yes, it is found and check so do something with item here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using new, you are creating a new item which is not added to the list view (since it is new) and can therefore not be found when using listView1.Contains(item).

When you add an item, use a key/value pair and use contains on the values.